# MandrillMailer Ruby Gem with Interceptors

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mailchimp, mailer, transactional-email

I am working with the Mandrill Mailer Ruby Gem (https://github.com/renz45/mandrill_mailer), but I am wanting to setup an interceptor so that in Development (and Staging) emails go to a different email address.

I am not sure how to go about doing this with working with the gem itself. I know how to do this if working with ActionMailer out of the box, but slightly confused on how to accomplish this outside of that.

Any ideas or anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me when using a template with the mandrill_mail method.

config/environments/test.rb

```
MandrillMailer.configure do |config|
  config.interceptor_params = { to: [email: 'homer@simpson.com', name: 'Homer Simpson'] }
end
```